# NestJS + MySQL: how to connect to multiple databases without setting entities

Tags: mysql, sql, typescript, nestjs, cross-database

The [NestJS documentation about Databases](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database) explains how to connect to MySQL using TypeORM and defining Entities.

In my case, I have to connect to an MySQL server that has more than one database and I need to execute SQL queries directly (without using the Entity layer) and fetch their results. Sometimes I also need to run **cross-database queries**.

How to do that using [NestJS](https://github.com/nestjs/nest)?

Comment: See "Multiple databases" section: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database. Each connection has its own name then, which you can use to inject connection instance to the class using @InjectConnection('name') (and connection has methods that enable you to execute plain SQL queries)

Comment: @KamilMyśliwiec thanks, but can I pass an empty array `[]` as `entities` in the `TypeOrmModule` ?

Answer (score 4):

You can import [multiple databases](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database) by given the connections different names. You can either directly pass the database configuration in separate `TypeOrmModule.forRoot({...})` imports or use a `ormconfig.json` config file. (However, the `ormconfig.json` file might still not work with multiple databases, see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51995362/4694994).)

```
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
  ...defaultOptions,
  name: 'personsConnection',
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  host:  'person_db_host',
  entities: [Person],
}),
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
  ...defaultOptions,
  name: 'albumsConnection',
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  host:  'album_db_host',
  // You can also leave the entities empty
  entities: [],
})
```

As stated by Kamil in the comments, you can inject the TypeORM [`connection`](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/connection-api.md#connection-api-1) object with  `@InjectConnection('albumsConnection'): Connection` and then use the [`QueryBuilder`](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/select-query-builder.md) or the method `query` to run raw SQL.

```
const rawData = await connection.query(`SELECT * FROM USERS`);
```

Comment: TypeOrmModule.forRoot() gave me an typescript error " is not assignable to parameter of type 'TypeOrmModuleOptions'" so I have used TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync() and everything worked smoothly