# TypeORM + FoalTS Multiple Database Connections

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express, typeorm, foalts

For some context, I'm building an NodeJS app with FoalTS which uses Express and TypeORM underneath.

My question is around how to implement [multiple database connections](https://typeorm.io/#/multiple-connections/using-multiple-connections) and accessing them [using a single connection](https://typeorm.io/#/multiple-connections/using-multiple-databases-in-a-single-connection)  by referencing by name.

In my `ormconfig.json` file, I have two database connections:

```js
module.exports = [
  {
    name: 'db1',
    type: 'mssql',
    database: 'ABC'
  ...
  },
  {
    name: 'db2',
    type: 'mssql',
    database: 'XYZ'
  ...
  }
]
```

And I reference the databases within the Entities:

```js
// reason.entity.ts
@Entity({ database: "ABC" })
export class Reason {
...
```

```js
// order.entity.ts
@Entity({ database: "XYZ" })
export class Order {
...
```

However I have an issue where one of the database connections needs to be named "default", otherwise the following error is thrown: `ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found.`

I found a [similar question asked on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51994541/nestjs-typeorm-use-two-or-more-databases), but the solution to that was aimed more towards NestJS.

I tried renaming `"db1"` to `"default"` in my `ormconfig.json` file, but then EVERY entity tries to use the default database connection,  even those with `@Entity({ database: "XYZ" })` specified.

So, I'm wondering if there is an [equivalent solution similar to the one suggested in the stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51995362), or if I should take a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should have a look to createConnections from typeorm instead of createConnection when the app initialized.
Doc createConnection:

> Creates a new connection and registers it in the manager. Only one
> connection from ormconfig will be created (name “default” or
> connection without name).

Take a look at https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/multiple-connections